# Inheritation of static function in JS

Tags: javascript, variables

Say I have four buttons, set out like so:

`Click me` (button 1) - `Or Click me` (button 2)

`option 1`(button 3) - `option 2` (button 4)

If I click on button 1 or 2, I want a local variable to be set to which button was pressed.

When I click on either button 3 or 4, I need to access the variable that holds which button was clicked and process it.

I would like to avoid creating variables in the global scope or using more than one. Is this even possible?

**What I've Tried:**

```
function setButtonId(i) {
  this.id = i
}
setbuttonId.process = item => {
  console.log(item)
}
//tmpcode
```

Comment: you know, I don't just ask questions to annoy the community, right? I ask questions because I need help, and I can't get unstuck.

Comment: Don't forget the `new` operator.

Comment: Kinda hoping to avoid that, but yes, it would work

Comment: Then instead of `this.id = 1` use `return {id: 1}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   const logic = {
    id: null,
    setId(i) {
     this.id = i;
    },
    process() {
     console.log(this.id);
    }
 };
```

And then use it as:

```
  button1.onclick = () => logic.setId(3);
  button4.onclick = () => logic.process();
```

But i would actually prefer a non-global outer scope variable:

```
 {
   let id = null;
   function setId(i){ id = i}
   function process() {
     console.log(id);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the straight answer. It worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid global variables then you can either use immediate invoked function expression:

```js
(function() {
  var lastId;
  document.getElementById("1").addEventListener('click', () => {
    lastId = 1;
  });

  document.getElementById("2").addEventListener('click', () => {
    lastId = 2;
  });

  document.getElementById("3").addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(lastId)
  });

  document.getElementById("4").addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(lastId)
  });
}())
```

```html
<button id="1">1</button><button id="2">2</button><button id="3">3</button><button id="4">4</button>
```

or `let`:

```js
{
  let lastId;
  document.getElementById("1").addEventListener('click', () => {
    lastId = 1;
  });

  document.getElementById("2").addEventListener('click', () => {
    lastId = 2;
  });

  document.getElementById("3").addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(lastId)
  });

  document.getElementById("4").addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(lastId)
  });
}
```

```html
<button id="1">1</button><button id="2">2</button><button id="3">3</button><button id="4">4</button>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! such an approach, I would not have come up with